# Big array with random numbers with python

Tags: python, arrays, random

I need to generate a big array (or list) with random numbers ( 10⁵ numbers) . I was trying like that:

```
vet = random.sample(range(10),100000)
```

But when I try to run :

```
vet = random.sample(range(10),10000)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 320, in sample
    raise ValueError("sample larger than population")
  ValueError: sample larger than population

Any solution?

tkns

Comment: Considering the size of that list, you might want to consider an array library like [numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/): `import numpy; vet = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10000)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you want is

```
[random.random() for _ in xrange(100000)]
```

From the [random module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html):

> random.sample(population, k) Return a k length list of unique elements
> chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without
> replacement.

so when calling `random.sample(range(10), 100000)` you're trying to extract 100000 unique elements in a sequence of length 10 which obviously can't work.

Note that

- `random.random()` returns a floating value between [0 ; 1)
- `random.randrange([start], stop[, step])` returns a random element from the sequence `range([start], stop[, step])`
- `random.randint(a, b)` returns an integer value in [a ; b]
- when using `random.sample`, the equality `len(population) >= k` must hold

Comment: Can't find module xrange

Comment: If you're using Python3, `xrange` (which was just a "lazy" `range`) is now simply `range`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014310/why-is-there-no-xrange-function-in-python3.

Answer (score 13):

I think you're after something like this:

```
vet = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(100000)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can you the numpy function and create an array with N space filled with a random number

```
import numpy as np

vector_size = 10000

one_dimensional_array  = np.random.rand(vector_size)
two_dimensional_array  = np.random.rand(vector_size, 2)
tree_dimensional_array = np.random.rand(vector_size, 3)
#and so on
```

[numpy.random.rand](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html)

You can create matrix of random numbers using the function below and arrays also.