# Why is there no xrange function in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep, xrange

Recently I started using Python3 and it's lack of `xrange` hurts.

Simple example:

1. Python2:

   ```
   from time import time as t
   def count():
     st = t()
     [x for x in xrange(10000000) if x%4 == 0]
     et = t()
     print et-st
   count()
   ```
2. Python3:

   ```
   from time import time as t

   def xrange(x):

       return iter(range(x))

   def count():
       st = t()
       [x for x in xrange(10000000) if x%4 == 0]
       et = t()
       print (et-st)
   count()
   ```

The results are, respectively:

1. `1.53888392448`
2. `3.215819835662842`

Why is that? I mean, why `xrange` has been removed? It's such a great tool to learn. For the beginners, just like myself, like we all were at some point. Why remove it? Can somebody point me to the proper PEP, I can't find it.

Comment: `range` in Python 3.x is `xrange` from Python 2.x. It was in fact Python 2.x's `range` that was removed.

Comment: PS, you should never time with `time`. Besides being easier to use and harder to get wrong, and repeating tests for you, `timeit` takes care of all kinds of things you won't remember, or even know how, to take care of (like disabling the GC), and may use a clock with thousands of times better resolution.

Comment: Also, why are you testing the time to filter the `range` on `x%4 == 0`? Why not just test `list(xrange())` vs. `list(range())`, so there's as little extraneous work as possible? (For example, how do you know 3.x isn't doing `x%4` more slowly?) For that matter, why are you building a huge `list`, which involves a whole lot of memory allocation (which, besides being slow, is also incredibly variable)?

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html , section "Views And Iterators Instead Of Lists": "range() now behaves like xrange() used to behave, except it works with values of arbitrary size. The latter no longer exists." So, range now returns an iterator. `iter(range)` is redundant.

Comment: Sorry, realized quoting the change doc doesn't make it blindingly obvious. For anyone else who is confused, and doesn't want to read through the long accepted answer, and all its comments:  **Wherever you were using xrange in python 2, use range in python 3. It does what xrange used to do, which is return an iterator. If you need the results in a list, do `list(range(..))`. That is equivalent to python 2's range.** Or to say it another way: **xrange has been renamed range, because it is the better default; it wasn't necessary to have both, do `list(range)` if you really need a list.**.

Comment: Clearly, ``list(range(...))`` is a necessary change.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: To be clear, neither Py2 `xrange` nor Py3 `range` return iterators. They return a low overhead immutable *sequence*, which, when iterated, implicitly converts to an iterator, like all sequences. So you don't even need to listify it normally (though in Python 2 it doesn't implemented the complete Sequence ABC, so it lacks certain features like slicing) if all you're doing is using immutable aspects of it. The only time you listify is when you need to change the contents later.

Comment: Even in this short example importing `time` as `t` obfuscates, and shortening a 4 character identifier is not a benefit in any context.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Some performance measurements, using `timeit` instead of trying to do it manually with `time`.

First, Apple 2.7.2 64-bit:

```
In [37]: %timeit collections.deque((x for x in xrange(10000000) if x%4 == 0), maxlen=0)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.05 s per loop
```

Now, python.org 3.3.0 64-bit:

```
In [83]: %timeit collections.deque((x for x in range(10000000) if x%4 == 0), maxlen=0)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.32 s per loop

In [84]: %timeit collections.deque((x for x in xrange(10000000) if x%4 == 0), maxlen=0)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.31 s per loop

In [85]: %timeit collections.deque((x for x in iter(range(10000000)) if x%4 == 0), maxlen=0) 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.33 s per loop
```

Apparently, 3.x `range` really is a bit slower than 2.x `xrange`. And the OP's `xrange` function has nothing to do with it. (Not surprising, as a one-time call to the `__iter__` slot isn't likely to be visible among 10000000 calls to whatever happens in the loop, but someone brought it up as a possibility.)

But it's only 30% slower. How did the OP get 2x as slow? Well, if I repeat the same tests with 32-bit Python, I get 1.58 vs. 3.12. So my guess is that this is yet another of those cases where 3.x has been optimized for 64-bit performance in ways that hurt 32-bit.

But does it really matter? Check this out, with 3.3.0 64-bit again:

```
In [86]: %timeit [x for x in range(10000000) if x%4 == 0]
1 loops, best of 3: 3.65 s per loop
```

So, building the `list` takes more than twice as long than the entire iteration.

And as for "consumes much more resources than Python 2.6+", from my tests, it looks like a 3.x `range` is exactly the same size as a 2.x `xrange`—and, even if it were 10x as big, building the unnecessary list is still about 10000000x more of a problem than anything the range iteration could possibly do.

And what about an explicit `for` loop instead of the C loop inside `deque`?

```
In [87]: def consume(x):
   ....:     for i in x:
   ....:         pass
In [88]: %timeit consume(x for x in range(10000000) if x%4 == 0)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.85 s per loop
```

So, almost as much time wasted in the `for` statement as in the actual work of iterating the `range`.

If you're worried about optimizing the iteration of a range object, you're probably looking in the wrong place.

---

Meanwhile, you keep asking why `xrange` was removed, no matter how many times people tell you the same thing, but I'll repeat it again: It was not removed: it was renamed to `range`, and the 2.x `range` is what was removed.

Here's some proof that the 3.3 `range` object is a direct descendant of the 2.x `xrange` object (and not of the 2.x `range` function): the source to [3.3 `range`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Objects/rangeobject.c) and [2.7 `xrange`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/rangeobject.c). You can even see the [change history](http://hg.python.org/cpython/diff/a6eb6acfe04a/Objects/rangeobject.c) (linked to, I believe, the change that replaced the last instance of the string "xrange" anywhere in the file).

So, why is it slower?

Well, for one, they've added a lot of new features. For another, they've done all kinds of changes all over the place (especially inside iteration) that have minor side effects. And there'd been a lot of work to dramatically optimize various important cases, even if it sometimes slightly pessimizes less important cases. Add this all up, and I'm not surprised that iterating a `range` as fast as possible is now a bit slower. It's one of those less-important cases that nobody would ever care enough to focus on. No one is likely to ever have a real-life use case where this performance difference is the hotspot in their code.

Comment: But it's only 30% slower.  

Still slower, but a great response mate, something to think about. It doesn't answer my quesion though: why was xrange removed??

Think about it this way - if you had a performance-dependant app based on multiprocessing knowing how much queue you need to consume a-time, would 30% make a difference or not? You see, you say it doesn't matter, but every time i use range i hear that huge distressing fan sound meaning cpu is on it's worst, while xrange doesn't do it. Think you about it ;)

Comment: @catalesia: Once again, it wasn't removed, it was just renamed `range`. The `range` object in 3.3 is a direct descendant of the `xrange` object in 2.7, not of the `range` function in 2.7. It's like asking while `itertools.imap` was removed in favor of `map`. There is no answer, because no such thing happened.

Comment: @catalesia: The minor performance changes are presumably not the result of a direct design decision to make ranges slower, but a side effect of 4 years of changes all over Python that have made many things faster, some things a little slower (and some things faster on x86_64 but slower on x86, or faster in some use cases but slower in others, etc.). Nobody was likely worried about a 30% difference either way in how long it takes to iterate a `range` while doing nothing else.

Comment: "Nobody was likely worried about a 30% difference either way in how long it takes to iterate a range _while doing nothing else._"  

Exactly.

Comment: @catalesia: Yes, exactly. But you seem to think that means the opposite of what it says. It's not a use case that anyone will ever care about, so nobody noticed that it got 30% slower. So what? If you can find a real-life program that runs more slowly in Python 3.3 than in 2.7 (or 2.6) because of this, people will care. If you can't, they won't, and you shouldn't either.

Comment: The spicy "once again..." comment brought me here from google! +1.

Answer (score 156):

Python3's range *is* Python2's xrange. There's no need to wrap an iter around it. To get an actual list in Python3, you need to use `list(range(...))`

If you want something that works with Python2 and Python3, try this

```
try:
    xrange
except NameError:
    xrange = range
```

Comment: Sometimes you need code that works in both Python 2 and 3. This is a good solution.

Comment: The trouble is that with this, code that uses both `range` and `xrange` will behave differently. It's not enough to do this, one would also have to make sure never to assume that `range` is returning a list (as it would in python 2).

Comment: You can use xrange from this project. There is `futurize` tool to automatically convert you source code: http://python-future.org/reference.html?highlight=xrange#past.builtins.xrange

Answer (score 23):

Python 3's `range` type works just like Python 2's `xrange`. I'm not sure why you're seeing a slowdown, since the iterator returned by your `xrange` function is exactly what you'd get if you iterated over `range` directly.

I'm not able to reproduce the slowdown on my system. Here's how I tested:

Python 2, with `xrange`:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in xrange(1000000) if x%4]",number=100)
18.631936646865853
```

Python 3, with `range` is a tiny bit faster:

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=100)
17.31399508687869
```

I recently learned that Python 3's `range` type has some other neat features, such as support for slicing: `range(10,100,2)[5:25:5]` is `range(20, 60, 10)`!

Comment: Perhaps the slowdown comes from the lookup of the new `xrange` so many times, or is that done only once?

Comment: Does an iterator actually increase speed anyway? I thought it just saved memory.

Comment: @askewchan Memory is everything, when it comes to heavy processor operations. I can class that method, but it still gives the same result. More-less. Anyway, I would be glad if anyone pointed me to the PEP explaining th reason behind removing xrange.

Comment: @askewchan It depends on how big the set is. Beyond a certain size, memory allocation (and garbage collection) represents a large part of the running time.

Comment: @catalesia I think the point here is that `xrange` was _not_ removed, just _renamed_.

Comment: @askewchan - renamed or not, it is much slower and consumes much more resources than Python 2.6+ Of course, one can build scipy and such, but come'on! I will not understand why a perfectly working solution was removed in order to... Exactly, what??

Comment: The removal of Python 2's `xrange` (with its semantics being given to `range` in Python 3) is mentioned briefly in [PEP 3100](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3100/#built-in-namespace).

Comment: @catalesia Dunno, I use 2.7 :P

Comment: @Blckknght: Cheers, but it still sucks having an explanation the likes of: "Set literals and comprehensions [19] [20] [done] {x} means set([x]); {x, y} means set([x, y]). {F(x) for x in S if P(x)} means set(F(x) for x in S if P(x)). NB. {range(x)} means set([range(x)]), NOT set(range(x)). There's no literal for an empty set; use set() (or {1}&{2} :-). There's no frozenset literal; **they are too rarely needed.**"

Comment: @askewchan: Hehe, 2.6 here, but we have to move on mate ;)

Comment: The biggest win in 3.x `range`, as far as I'm concerned, is the constant-time `__contains__`. Newbies used to write `300000 in xrange(1000000)` and that caused it to iterate the whole `xrange` (or at least the first 30% of it), so we had to explain why that was a bad idea, even though it looks so pythonic. Now, it _is_ pythonic.

Comment: Newbies are the base of Python, never forget that. Python, or any language of the sort. G'Night people!

Comment: @catalesia: Agreed 100%. That was my point—they replaced `range.__contains__` solely to make it work the way newbies expected—and that was a great change.

Comment: @catalesia The reference in PEP 3100 is `Make built-ins return an iterator where appropriate (e.g. range() ...) To be removed: ... xrange(): use range() instead`. The PEP has a reference to a [talk given by Guido](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/pycon2003/pycon2003.ppt) (the creator of Python) explaining the reason for the change. Part of Python's design philosophy is that "there should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it". Having both `range` and `xrange` violated the "only one" part of that principle.

Answer (score 2):

One way to fix up your python2 code is:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    def xrange(*args, **kwargs):
        return iter(range(*args, **kwargs))
```

Comment: The point is in python3 xrange is not defined, so legacy code that used xrange breaks.

Comment: no , simply define `range = xrange` as is in comment by @John La Roy

Comment: @mimi.vx Not sure range=xrange would work in Python3 because xrange is not defined. My comment refers to the case where you have old legacy code that contains xrange calls AND your trying to get it to run under python3.

Comment: Ah , my bad .. `xrange = range` ... i switched statements

Comment: range *IS* an iiterator, and anyway this would be a terrible idea even if it wasn't, because it has to unpack the the entire range first and loses the advantages of using an iterator for this sort of thing. So the correct response is not "range=xrange" its "xrange=range"

Comment: @Shayne I think your right I would go with John La Roy's solution below now, it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

xrange from Python 2 is a generator and implements iterator while range is just a function.
In Python3 I don't know why was dropped off the xrange.

Comment: No, range is not an interator. You can't do next() with this structure. For further info, you can check here http://treyhunner.com/2018/02/python-range-is-not-an-iterator/

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification.  But I will restate the intent of the original comment, and that is that PY3 `range()` is the equivalent of PY2 `xrange()`.  And thus in PY3 `xrange()` is redundant.

Comment: @MichelFernandes: Though `xrange` wasn't a generator or an iterator either; like Py 3's `range` (which is literally just Py 2 `xrange` renamed and expanded a little), it was a sequence object that was iter*able*, but not an iter*ator*. It didn't implement *all* `Sequence` ABC features (omitting slicing for instance), but you could do `sq = xrange(12, 100, 3)` and then do `seq[5]` to determine the sixth element in the sequence of numbers.

Answer (score -1):

**comp:~$ python** 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in xrange(1000000) if x%4]",number=100)
```

5.656799077987671

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in xrange(1000000) if x%4]",number=100)
```

5.579368829727173

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=100)
```

21.54827117919922

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=100)
```

22.014557123184204

**With timeit number=1 param:**

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=1)
```

0.2245171070098877

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in xrange(1000000) if x%4]",number=1)
```

0.10750913619995117

**comp:~$ python3**
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=100)
```

9.113872020003328

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=100)
```

9.07014398300089

**With timeit number=1,2,3,4 param works quick and in linear way:**

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=1)
```

0.09329321900440846

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=2)
```

0.18501482300052885

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=3)
```

0.2703447980020428

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=4)
```

0.36209142999723554

So it seems if we measure 1 running loop cycle like timeit.timeit("[x for x in range(1000000) if x%4]",number=1) (as we actually use in real code) python3 works quick enough, but in repeated loops python 2 xrange() wins in speed against range() from python 3.

Comment: but this is by language itself ... nothing to do with xrange/range.