# pandas initialize dataframe column cells as empty lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I need to initialize the cells in a column of a `DataFrame` to `lists`.

```
df['some_col'] = [[] for _ in no_of_rows]
```

I am wondering is there a better way to do that in terms of time efficiency?

Comment: You have accepted an answer that offers a solution 3x slower than your starting point.

Comment: @Stefan it seems that you are correct, as `apply(list)` is indeed slightly slower than my old code.

Comment: So as you can see below you can get  a tiny bit faster using `itertools`, but I think you're actually quite good already because I don't see a faster way to add the column than the standard method, but perhaps someone comes up with some magic..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are looking for time efficiency, below some benchmarks. I think `list` comprehension is already quite fast to create the empty `list` of `list` objects, but you can squeeze out a marginal improvement using `itertools.repeat`. On the `insert` piece, `apply` is 3x slower because it loops:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import repeat
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":np.arange(100000)})

%timeit df['some_col'] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]
100 loops, best of 3: 8.75 ms per loop

%timeit df['some_col'] = [[] for i in repeat(None, len(df))]
100 loops, best of 3: 8.02 ms per loop

%%timeit 
df['some_col'] = ''
df['some_col'] = df['some_col'].apply(list)
10 loops, best of 3: 25 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

Try [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df1['some_col'] = ''
df1['some_col'] = df1['some_col'].apply(list)
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series([1,2])})
print (df1)
   a
0  1
1  2

df1['some_col'] = ''
df1['some_col'] = df1['some_col'].apply(list)
print (df1)
   a some_col
0  1       []
1  2       []
```

Comment: How is this better in terms of time efficiency?

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is not better in terms of time efficiency. But it is up to OP which answer sign as accepted. Maybe you prefer me, because I was first, maybe because like it. But maybe in few seconds change his opinion. I dont know.

Comment: Also note that `lambda: []` will be faster than `list`.

Comment: Just asking because the question was about time efficiency, so it's a good thing if the answer tries to do so as well.

Comment: @Stefan And now maybe your solution will be accepted.

Comment: @Stefan what about `xrange` ? `%timeit df['some_col'] = [[] for _ in xrange(len(df))]` . Unfortunately I cannot test it, because it works in python 2.

Comment: `xrange` has been renamed to `range` in python3 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014310/why-is-there-no-xrange-function-in-python3 and GvR: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists